# Codeigniter Session Tokens

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I what is the best way to get codeigniter session tokens working? Do they have them? I am trying to be able to do something like this `site_url(user, 'token=' . $this->session->userdata('token'). $url);`

I am not sure the best way to implement this in sessions. To where it generates a token for sessions.

Can not seem to find any good information on it in Google. Any ideas?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cross-site request forgery (CSRF)**

You can enable csrf protection by opening your application/config/config.php file and setting this:

```
$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;
```

**NOTE:
If you use the form helper the form_open() function will automatically insert a hidden csrf field in your forms.

If you want to user normal forms :

```
$data['my_token'] = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
$_SESSION['my_token'] = $data['my_token'];

// During page rendering:
<input type="hidden" name="my_token" id="my_token" value="<? php echo $_SESSION['my_token']?>" />

// After they click submit, when checking form:
if ($_POST['my_token'] === $_SESSION['my_token'])
{
        // was ok
}
else
{
          // was bad!!!
}
```